# Adding extra backslash in the column value in the generated sql file from generateChangeLog using maven Liquibase

Tags: liquibase

After generating an sql file from updateSql goal in maven in liquibase I can see extra backslash has been added in the column value of the table. I have figure it out that I can prevent this by using CDATA but I am not able to find any property in liquibase maven.

Original Value of the Column:

http(s)?://([\da-zA-Z.-]+).([a-zA-Z.]{2,6})([/\w .-]*)*/?(\?)?.*$

Value after UpdateSql goal:

http(s)?:\/\/([\da-zA-Z\.-]+)\.([a-zA-Z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?(\?)?.*$

Please let me know if there is solution to use it in maven plugin with liquibase

Comment: Did you try with CDATA? Does it not work?

Comment: @Jens , I tried to find the way for using CDATA in liquibase maven configuration as I am generating the sql Scripts from generateChangeLog dynamically using maven configuration. but haven't found any solution yet.